# Datagridview column header bigger C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Im using WinForm. I have a datagridview with a couple columns. I want to know how to make the font of each column header bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the font on the header cell like:

```
dataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font(... etc
```

Or for all columns:

```
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(... etc
```

Comment: Thank you. With your help I used this code dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Calibri", 16F);

Answer (score 1):

But if thats possible I would recommend to do that by designer (its better if you have styles, etc. in designer.cs)